# where can i find simple example of Mozilla plug-in that mimic firebug element inspection function

Tags: firefox-addon

How does Firebug implement the "element inspection function"?
I do not have experience in Firefox development but I am an experienced developer. 
I'm trying to avoid divining into Firebug source code because I need only this function.
What will be the fastest way to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the best thing to do **is** to read it's Source Code, since you want a inspection feature exactly like Firebug.

It's source is available online at [google code](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.6/content/firebug/), and you can have some more information about Firebug structure in [Firebug Internals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firebug_internals) page of Mozilla's Developer Center.

Firebug uses mainly javascript in it's core: take a look at [inspector.js](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.6/content/firebug/inspector.js) to understand it's inspection feature.